# How to add each item in a list to the previous one in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list and I want to add each element in the list to the previous one. For example if I have the list `(1,1,3,3,4)`, I want the program to output `(1,2,5,8,12)`.

Comment: Wouldn't adding each element "to the previous one" give you (2,4,6,7,4)?

Comment: @ScottHunter..i think the OP meant cumulative sum based on his expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
[sum(a[:i]) for i in range(1,len(a)+1)]
```

is probably the easiest way ... I guess ...

```
numpy.cumsum(a)
```

would also work i think

Answer (score 2):

using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([1,1,3,3,4], lambda total,el: total+el))
[1, 2, 5, 8, 12]
```

*disclaimer*: added in python 3.2

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    arr[i] += arr[i - 1]
```

more efficient than Joran Beasley loop

Comment: ^_^ ... not really if its big enough to impact speedwise the numpy version is what he should really use :P +1 all the same ... just maybe a little less clear to the reader that it is a cumulative sum

Comment: yea i am sure numpy.cumsum was implemented as fast as possible i was talking about the first loop